# The MongoDB PECL extension has not been installed or enabled, centos?

Tags: php, mongodb, codeigniter-3, pecl

I'm using Centos 7, and when I tried to load MongoDB library in CodeIgniter 3, 
[https://github.com/intekhabrizvi/Codeigniter-mongo-library/blob/master/application/libraries/Mongo_db.php][1]

it is showing the error

> ```
> An Error Was Encountered
> The MongoDB PECL extension has not been installed or enabled
> ```

I already have `extension=mongodb.so` in my php.ini file,

> OS :Centos            : 7,
>    php version : 7.1.18,
>   MongoDB shell version : v3.4.15.

Any help or suggestions will be highly useful.

Comment: https://github.com/intekhabrizvi/Codeigniter-mongo-library/issues/32

Answer (score 0):

Check if the MongoDB extension is properly installed on your system by running the php -m
command on your terminal and looking for the mongodb module in the list of loaded modules.

```
Step 1: Install apache(httpd) and php 7

Step 2: Install php-pear
install gcc php-pear php-devel

Step 3: Install mongodb extension 
pecl install mongodb

Step 4: Enable php-mongodb extension 
open php.ini file, then add the following line

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Dynamic Extensions ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
extension=mongodb

Step 5: Verify PHP Mongodb extension is enabled
php -m
```

OR
If the mongodb module is not loaded, you'll need to install it. You can do this using the package manager for your system. For example, on CentOS, you can install the MongoDB extension using the following
command: **sudo yum install php-pecl-mongodb.**

If the mongodb module is loaded, you may need to check if it's enabled for your Apache server. You can do this by creating a new PHP file in your Apache server's document root directory containing the following code: